# NoSuchMethodError when deployed on linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, tomcat

I have the following code that reads from a file:

```
private static void writeLogs(String filePath, PrintWriter writer)throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fullFilePath = AppConfig.getAppDir()+"/auditlogs/"+filePath+".log";
    System.out.println("loading log files from --> "+fullFilePath);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullFilePath));
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<String>();
        do {
            line = br.readLine();
            tmp.add(line);

        }while (line != null);
        for(int i=tmp.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
            if(tmp.get(i)!=null){
                sb.append(tmp.get(i));
                sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }
        String logs = sb.toString();
        writer.write(logs);
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

This works as expected when I deploy on tomcat server on windows. When I try to the same on linux, the files don't get read. On inspecting the tomcat log file I see:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ReadLogsServlet threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.lineSeparator()Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.ericsson.ims.web.servlet.ReadLogsServlet.writeLogs(ReadLogsServlet.java:53)
    at com.ericsson.ims.web.servlet.ReadLogsServlet.doGet(ReadLogsServlet.java:26)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

The error occurs due to `System.lineSeparator()`but when I check the javadoc, it says:

> Returns the system-dependent line separator string. It always returns
>   the same value - the initial value of the system property
>   line.separator.
>
> On UNIX systems, it returns "\n"; on Microsoft Windows systems it
>   returns "\r\n".

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work and how to fix so it will work on multiple platforms?

Comment: Does your system have jre7? `System.lineSeparator()` is a new method in java 1.7

Comment: What about `System.getProperty("line.separator")` ? `lineSeparator()` method is introduced as of java 1.7...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you are not using the same version of Java between Linux and Windows.

As you can see [in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html), `System.lineSeparator()` doesn't exists in java < 7.

So, if you want to get the line separator on java < 7, you have to use:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are running **different JDK versions** on Windows and Linux.

- On Windows the JDK is 7 which has [System.lineSeparator(](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)) method defined.
- The same method does not exist in the previous JDK verions  (check [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class in Java 6) which is running on your Linux box.

For the backward compatible code use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out there is an issue with the versions.
I would dare to say that merely changing the JVM is not enough.
Your program could check for the expected version at startup to avoid such issues **in the future**:

> ```
> String runtimeName = System.getProperty("java.runtime.name");
> String runtimeVersion = System.getProperty("java.runtime.version");
> ... check if JVM is the expected one, log some informative message if not ...
> ```

You can also do this for other settings (Locale ...) but those depend on the nature of your project. The idea is that **a dead program is better than a crippled one** (fail fast), another idea is that you should **fix an issue once and for all** (find bugs once).
You can find more tips here: http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips

Answer (score 0):

`System.lineSeparator()` is introduced in `Java 7`. So it seems you are using an earlier version on your Linux machine. You can use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get it or upgrade your java version on your linux machine.